MuseScore Repeat Slurs

As you can see in my image, there is a slur going from the second to last triplet to the note that lasts 3 beats. After the repeat, that slur must finish on the very last note that lasts 3 beats after the repeat. Also, I have the same problem elsewhere in this music: At the very start there is a Slur from before the repeat till a 1.5 beat. After the repeat the last note before the repeat is meant to replace the start of slur. Is there a way to do this in MuseScore 3?
Also, can anyone guess the song?

Thanks, Force theme from Star Wars.

See also How to tie the first note of the second volta in MuseScore?.

I no longer have Musescore 3 available.  But if it's the same in Musescore 4...
Slurs can be freely moved.  Look at the one I created by selecting the last note and pressing S.  The indicated handle shifts the whole thing, the other handles can be used to shape it. The one into the preceding dotted half is the finished product.


yes but it wont sound the same also did you use that same technique for the last 3 beat note?

@PianoCat98 - From all my time using Musescore playback, Musescore does not respect slurs in playback, not even for instruments where respecting slurs makes an audible difference (such as clarinets).

@PianoCat98  Yes, I used that technique to make the one into the preceding dotted half, the one that your question was all about!

I recall doing something similar in Musescore 3 with a tie instead of a slur. I had to use an invisible, inaudible note in the ending measure of the first repeat to attach the other end of the tie(/slur for you) to. This meant using invisible rests to place the invisible note in the correct position.
You can do a similar trick to place a one-ended slur on the last RH note of the first repeat. Make an invisible, inaudible note at the start of the second repeat and place the other end of the slur on that.

but this is just a segment this isnt the end
